# LINQ - Getting all child records from all parents

Tags: c#, linq

I have two models:

```
class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }    
}

class Bar
{
    public int Value { get; set; }    
}
```

Having an instance of `List<Foo>`, how can I get all `Value` using a LINQ query?

Thank you all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SelectMany` is normally the way to flatten hierarchies, so:

```
var values = myList.SelectMany(foo => foo.Bar)
                   .Select(bar => bar.Value);
```

The `SelectMany` will give you an `IEnumerable<Bar>`, and then the `Select` projects that sequence of `Bar` objects to the `Value` property of each, returning an `IEnumerable<int>`.

As a query expression, this would be:

```
var values = from foo in myList
             from bar in foo.Bar
             select bar.Value;
```

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to change `List<Bar>` property name to `Bars`.

And firstly use [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence. And then use [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to project each element of a new sequence as you wish.

```
var result = myList.SelectMany(x => x.Bars).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`

```
var result = LIST1.SelectMany(x => x.LIST2.Select(y => y.Value)).Tolist();
```